# Multiple indexes iteration in Python's for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 4 lists, I want to iterate through the fours at once. here's an example of what I want to achieve

I'm on Python 3.8

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [10,20,30]
list3 = [44,55,66]
list4 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for i,j,k,,l in (list1, list2, list3, list4):
    print(i,j,k,l)
```

Output:

```
1, 10, 44, a
2, 20, 55, b
3, 30, 66, c
```

How can I achieve that ?

Thanks,

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Come in late, all prev. posts have done great answering the question. Here is to sum up and answer - `what if I want to different ordering` on the 4 items:

```
>>> for value_tpl in zip(list1, list2, list3, list4):
    n1, n2, n3, label = value_tpl
    print(label, n3, n2, n1)

    
A 44 10 1
B 55 20 2
C 66 30 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for this:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [10,20,30]
list3 = [44,55,66]
list4 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for i in range(len(list1)):
    print(list1[i], list2[i], list3[i], list4[i])
```

You loop through using a loop counter `i`, which is a list index. Then, you index each of the lists at that index to retrieve the values.

You may also want to read more about the [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function in Python, which in this case returns a sequence of numbers starting at 0 and finishing at `len(list1) - 1`, allowing you to loop through using `i` as an index.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was looking for a way more 'elegant' way to do it, I know how to do it with 2 indexes (for i,j in zip(list1, list2), ans was looking out of curiosity if you can do it for more than 2 lists

Answer (score 2):

Use zip to combine each list together and iterate through them

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [10,20,30]
list3 = [44,55,66]
list4 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for values in zip(list1, list2, list3, list4):
    print(*values)
```

Output:

```
1 10 44 a
2 20 55 b
3 30 66 c
```

As `values` will contain a tuple, the `*` will unpack it for you.

Comment: What If I don't want to print them, I want to do something different with each index ?

Comment: ```values``` in this case contains the first element of each list, you can do what ever you want, print was only based on your example.

Comment: "values will contain a list" => should be a tuple

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but we can zip all 4 list and read them:

```
for i in zip(list1,list2,list3,list4):
    print(i)
```